# For what reason would someone call the condition to call a function inside the function?

Tags: function, if-statement

Like the Title says:
Lately I've been reverse engineering  a litlle bit and found a function which essentially does this:

```
void the_function(int a) {
       if(a) {
            // do stuff here
            return; }
        return; }
```

My question is, why would one want to do this? Wouln't checking for the condition before the function call be more efficient? So instead doing this:

```
// do stuff
if(a) { 
      the_function(a) // now without the conditional in the function
 }
// do even more stuff
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you tell us an example of a real function defined as above ? I mean what function you have that takes a boolean(int as boolean and I assume you're using C) and returns void ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to understand because it seems like you are using pseudo code to describe your problem.

But I'll give it a stab anyway.

```
1    void the_function(int a) {
2           if(a) {
3                // do stuff here
4                return; }
5            return; }
```

if there is no code between line 4 and 5, then yes, this is just redundant code. Just remove the return inside the if statement, or do as you described yourself.

The code is likely left over from a time when the below statement was true.

If there is code between 4 and 5 then no! 
it's quite likely vital that the return statement is placed where it is. 
Because the additional code must not be run, if a == true.
by allowing the function to have a different purpose depending on the parameter you supply it with,
the return statement will effectively end the function/method call early, and allow two different sets of behaviour. Depending on the parameter.

Would it be better to make seperate functions for each action/branch? likely yes, but depends on your design really. I would argue its better to be consistant, so if one design is used predominantly, I would defer that this method wins, until someone argues why it shouldn't be done at all.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer ( @niksofteng you too)! So if I understand correctly, then it makes only sense if the function does something else, which makes sense. I will look through the code again, I may have I missed something :-)

Comment: It makes sense, but if you didnt miss any code Id wager a case of beer, that it's due to a sloppy code clean up, that has left the function in this state. It wouldnt really matter execution wise, because the code would work. Its just sloppy.

Answer (score 2):

When coming from the OO perspective, option 2 could be seen as violation of the [TDA](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle: instead of **telling** that function to do its job, the *client* has to know how to "check" whether `a` has a value that allows for calling that function.

Meaning: if `a` is something that `the_function()` needs to know about - why is it that a user of that function needs to know such details as well?

As said; when you come from the OO side of things, you rather intend to **hide** such aspects as far as possible. Example: assume that the condition needs to be changed to `if (a == 0 || a == 1)`. If `the_function()` checks internally, you only change the condition within the function. But if you "outline" that checking ... you **duplicated** code (to all the places where you call `the_function()`) - and now you will have to update all those usages accordingly. And with a certain probability, you will miss one out of 10, 20 usages. And so bugs come into existence!

Long story short: as a user, you don't want to be burden to understand what happens **inside** a function you are calling. You want to understand the public contract of that function; and that's it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You got a point wirh this being a pure design choice for user friendlyness, but I'm afraid, I will claim MortenBrock's answer as the solution. It just felt more sensical in my case.

Comment: :-) I will do this as soon as I am back at my PC (the App kinda makes problems regarding these things)

Comment: I never use the app; I found that *chrome* is working "good enough" for me when using the Mobile. But you are sure correct; tasks like "opening the profile of another user to search for upvote worth content" is much easier to do when using a desktop system ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Answers are going to be opinion based where mostly #2 would find more supporters. However, my vote goes to both approaches and which one works well depends on the scenario.

I would go with #2 When preconditions are obvious.

```
read > "please input no between 1 and 10"
input > 11

if (number >= 1 && number <= 10) {
    // Input looks good, proceed, call XYZ()
}
else {
    // Err, shout
}
```

This makes more sense when you write code that others are going to use (say library, API) which will otherwise not perform intended operations and caller will be left clueless as to why it didn't do so!

Vs #1 when you can't check preconditions

```
function GetEmployee(id) {
    if (employee_with_id_left_org) {
        // this is checked against data store
    }
    else {
        // return employee details
    }
}
```